# Why do we define discrete valuation rings through field of fractions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I'm trying to understand the following characterization of DVRs through discrete valuations  on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring):

> There is some discrete valuation $ν$ on the field of fractions $K$ of $R$ such that $R = \{0\}  \cup  \{x\in  K : ν(x) ≥ 0\}$

Why don't we directly define a discrete valuation for $R$, consider the elements of it which have a valuation greater than $0$ union it with the $0$ element and a create a DVR?

Comment: Equivalently, $R$ is an integral domain, not a field, there is a discrete valuation on $R$, and $v(a)\ge v(b)$ implies $a/b\in R$.

Comment: So, how does that help with problem statement @reuns

Comment: Try that with $R = \mathbf Z$: on it define the $p$-adic valuation ${\rm ord}_p$, which is a nonnegative integer on all nonzero elements of $R$. Where is the DVR? (Note: please try to stop calling them discrete evaluation rings, which is not their name. I corrected that in your post.)